# The remote server returned an error: NotFound

Tags: silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

I am using MVVM pattern for Silverlight.

I have these projects:

> MVVMDemo.Data (Ria services link set to MVVMDemo.Data.Web)
>   MVVMDemo.Data.Web (Contains all RIA services) MVVMDemo.Data.ViewModels
>   MVVMDemo.Data.Models MVVMDemo (contains all views)
>   MVVMDemo.Data.Common (contains all interfaces)

This is my RIA services class:

```
namespace MVVMDemo.Data.Web
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.EntityFramework;
    using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting;
    using System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server;



    [EnableClientAccess()]
    public class UserServices : LinqToEntitiesDomainService<IssueVisionEntities>
    {

        public IQueryable<User> GetUsersByLimit(int skip , int take)
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.Users.Skip(skip).Take(take);
        }

        public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.Users;
        }

        public void InsertUser(User user)
        {
            if ((user.EntityState != EntityState.Detached))
            {
                this.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user, EntityState.Added);
            }
            else
            {
                this.ObjectContext.Users.AddObject(user);
            }
        }

        public void UpdateUser(User currentUser)
        {
            this.ObjectContext.Users.AttachAsModified(currentUser, this.ChangeSet.GetOriginal(currentUser));
        }

        public void DeleteUser(User user)
        {
            if ((user.EntityState == EntityState.Detached))
            {
                this.ObjectContext.Users.Attach(user);
            }
            this.ObjectContext.Users.DeleteObject(user);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my model which calls RIA services :-

```
namespace MVVMDemo.Models
{
    [Export(typeof(IUserModel))]
    public class UserModel : IUserModel
    {
        private const int PAGESIZE = 10;
        private int skip = 0;


        private UserServices _context;
        private UserServices Context
        {
            get
            {
                if (_context == null)
                {
                    _context = new UserServices();
                }
                return _context;
            }
        }

        public void GetAllUsersAysnc()
        {
            PerformQuery<User>(Context.GetUsersQuery(), GetAllUsersAsyncComplete);
        }

        private void PerformQuery<T>(EntityQuery<T> query , EventHandler<EntityResultArgs<T>> eventHandler) where T:Entity
        {
            this.Context.Load<T>(query, LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, r =>
            {
                if (eventHandler != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (r.HasError)
                        {
                            eventHandler(this, new EntityResultArgs<T>(r.Error));
                            r.MarkErrorAsHandled();
                        }
                        else
                            eventHandler(this, new EntityResultArgs<T>(r.Entities));
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        eventHandler(this, new EntityResultArgs<T>(ex));
                    }

                }
            },null);
        }

        public event EventHandler<EntityResultArgs<Data.Web.User>> GetAllUsersAsyncComplete;

        public void GetAllUsersByLimit()
        {
            PerformQuery<User>(Context.GetUsersByLimitQuery(skip,PAGESIZE), GetAllUsersByLimitAsyncComplete);
        }

        public event EventHandler<EntityResultArgs<Data.Web.User>> GetAllUsersByLimitAsyncComplete;
    }
```

Whenever i run the method `GetAllUsersAysnc` i always get this error :-

http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/6150/62968542.jpg

This is my app.config in MVVMDemo.Data.Web

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" preCondition="managedHandler"
        type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="IssueVisionEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/IssueVisionModel.csdl|res://*/IssueVisionModel.ssdl|res://*/IssueVisionModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=TAPESH\MSSQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=IssueVision;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.web>    
    <httpModules>
      <add name="DomainServiceModule" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHttpModule, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>


</configuration>
```

And this is my web.config of Asp.Net website which is hosting the silverlight application

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

I have no idea what is happening and I am a beginner in RIA services.

Comment: The problem got resolved by adding the same contents as app.config to web.config and by adding reference of data.web project to my web project which is hosting silverlight application. Can anybody tell me why is this happening?

Comment: App.config never gets aggregated into web.config. You'll always need to copy things into your website's web.config file (connection strings, modules, etc).

Comment: @Kyle McClellan :- So is this a bug or a standard thing?

Comment: Standard. Web.config is an ASP.NET concept and makes a little more sense in that world. With Silverlight, you've got to put everything in a single file.